# unsupported: Symbol in Cucumber on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am trying to call `each` on an `ActiveRecord` object/list in RoR as shown in the following chunk of code.

```
 41 Then /I should (not )?see movies with ratings: (.*)/ do |not_see, rating_li>
 42   @movies = Movie.where(:rating, rating_list.split(", "))
 43   rating_list.split(",").map do |x|
 44     x.strip
 45   end.each do |rating|
 46     if not_see
 47       @movies.each do |movie|
 48         @movie.title
 49       end
 50     else
 51       puts "hello"
 52     end
 53   end
 54 end
```

And this produces the following error message:

```
And I should not see movies with ratings: G, PG-13, NC-17 # features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:41
  unsupported: Symbol (RuntimeError)
  ./features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  ./features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:45:in `each'
  ./features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:45:in `/I should (not )?see movies with ratings: (.*)/'
  features/filter_movie_list.feature:33:in `And I should not see movies with ratings: G, PG-13, NC-17'
```

Removing line `47` in the code above gets rid of the error. Why is that? As far as I can tell, all of these are valid Ruby code. What am I missing?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of code that was causing the error is line `42`. The call to `where` should have been:

```
Movie.where(:rating => rating_list.split(","))
```

`"=>"` and not `","`